# Does file name matter in uploading files in autodesk-realitycapture files api

Tags: autodesk-realitycapture

Once the files have been uploaded, in response I'm getting only .jpg as file name not the uploaded file name like below
"Files":{"file":[{"filename":".jpg","fileid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=-3679219-100000000","filesize":"3679219","msg":"No error"}]}

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you are not getting back the filename, but it should not really mater, as long as the filesize is correct - otherwise it is a sign that the file might be corrupted.
It would be interesting to know how you upload the file - maybe we could identify the couse of name stripping.

Comment: Then, I am afraid, the problem is in the code used to upload the file. 
If you haven't already, use Postman to upload the files (using this collection:https://github.com/apprentice3d/forge-api-go-client/tree/master/assets/PostmanCollections), and check again. If the file was uploaded correctly, then it confirms that the uploading code is the problem.